# Copy into `arr3` all those entries from `arr1` that exist in `arr2`

Tags: php, arrays

What is the easiest way to copy into `arr3` all those entries from `arr1` that exist in `arr2`? Is it possible to do this without using FOR loop?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
$arr3 = array_intersect($arr1, $arr2);
```

Or, if `$arr3` has items you wish to preserve, you can [merge](http://php.net/array_merge) the old array and the result of the function call:

```
$arr3 = array_merge($arr3, array_intersect($arr1, $arr2));
```